# Call URL in Background

Tags: javascript, html

I have a URL which turns on the light in a room, this URL works when I execute it in a normal browser. But now I have a image and with a onclick event, I want this URL to be executed in background to turn on the light.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LightOnOff(URL)
    {
        var temp = new Image();
        temp.src = "http://camera-kkw.at/axis-cgi/io/port.cgi?action=1:/1000%5C?";
        temp.onload = function(){document.location.href=URL};
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The image I press on to call the function:

```
<img alt="Light on/off" src="images/lamp.png" onclick="return LightOnOff(window.location.href)">
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetch` in order to remotely trigger the endpoint. You could add an `onClick` handler to the image and then execute the request:

```
function onClick() {
  fetch('http://camera-kkw.at/axis-cgi/io/port.cgi?action=1:/1000%5C?')
    .then(res => alert('Success'))
    .catch(err => alert('Failed));
}
```

Comment: Hello Vasil, thank you for your quick reply!
But unfortunately, this does not seem to work..

Comment: You would need to modify the `img` tag like so: `<img onclick="onClick" />`

Comment: I modified the img-tag like you said, but I get no response on my website. Is there no way to simply load a URL silent in background when I click on a image?

Comment: You could append an image with `display: none` to the page and trigger the request this way.

Comment: But how do I trigger the image to call the URL silent in the background without reloading the page? I'm sorry, I am a very beginner of html with javascript